# Django ModelForm to have a hidden input

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So I have my TagStatus model. I'm trying to make a ModelForm for it. However, my form requires that the hidden input be populated with the {{ tag.name }}. I've been looking through the docs and I don't know how to make the tag field a hidden input. Perhaps a ModelForm isn't the way to go?

**models.py:**

```
class TagStatus(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=tag_statuses)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.status

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TagStatus, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class TagStatusForm(modelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TagStatus
        fields = ('status','tag') 
        widgets = {
             'select': Select,
             'tag': ???
        }
```

**django views.py:**

```
@login_required
def tags(request):
    all_tags = Tag.objects.all()
    context = base_context(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'status_check' in request.POST:
            status_form = TagStatusForm(request.POST)
            #if request.is_ajax():
            if status_form.is_valid():
                status_form.save()
                response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Successfully changed status"})
            else:
                response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Error"})
                return HttpResponse (response, mimetype='application/json')
    status_form = TagStatusForm()
    context['status_form'] = status_form
    context['all_tags'] = all_tags
    return render_to_response('tags/tags.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template:

```
{% for tag in all_tags %}
....
<form class="nice" id="status-form" method="POST" action="">
     {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="status_check" />
      <input type='hidden' name="tag" value="{{ tag.name }}" />
     {{ status_form.status }}
</form>
...
{% endfor %}
```

How would I go about making a hidden input through a django ModelForm and then populate it through the template?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

To make a field in a ModelField a hidden field, use a HiddenInput widget.  The ModelForm uses a sensible default widget for all the fields, you just need to override it when the object is constructed.

```
class TagStatusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TagStatus
        widgets = {'tag': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

Comment: Works with Django 3.2

Answer (score 93):

There are 3 possible ways (AFAIK) to render hidden fields in Django -

**1.** You could declare a field normally in `forms.py` but in your templates html file use `{{ form.field.as_hidden }}`

**2.** in `forms.py` directly use hidden input widget.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    hidden_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

Once you make the field a hidden input, you could populate the value of the field in templates. Now your hidden field is ready for rendering.

**3.** Regular form equivalent (thanks to @Modelesq for sharing this nugget). Here no Django is involved. Changes are done at HTML template level. `<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="{{ tag.name }}" />`

Comment: How about I go about populating it? It's regular form equivalent would look like: `<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="{{ tag.name }}" />`

Comment: Did you find how to populate ? using `{{ tag.name }}` doesn't seem to work. I myself need `{{ forloop.counter }}`…

Comment: Any chance you could add the template side of things?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a way to HIDE ALL INPUTS :

```
class TagStatusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TagStatus

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TagStatusForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Comment: I get **django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'myField' cannot be specified for myModel model form as it is a non-editable field**. So I need to make it editable, but I still want it hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a way to do it with generic class-based views [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/34HJqx48h6Y):

```
from django.forms import HiddenInput

from django.forms.models import modelform_factory

_patient_create_form = modelform_factory(
    models.Patient,
    fields=['name', 'caregiver_name', 'sex', 'birth_date',
            'residence', 'country'],
    widgets={'country': HiddenInput()})

class PatientCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, UserOrgRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = _patient_create_form
    template_name = 'healthdbapp/patient_form.html'
```