# Django model choice field - depend on other field's choice

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I need django modelform with 2 fields, where second field choice list depends on what was chosen in first one. My model:

```
class Offer(BaseModel):

    VEHICLE_TYPES = (
        ('personal','Personal car'),
        ('truck','Truck'),
    )
    vehicle_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=VEHICLE_TYPES, default='personal', verbose_name='Vehicle type')

    PERSONAL_MAKES = (
        ('',''),
    )
    TRUCK_MAKES = (
        ('',''),
    )
    make = models.CharField(max_length=32)#what more??
```

How can I set choices of *make* field to *PERSONAL_MAKES* if vehicle_type is set to *personal*? How can I do this? Is it possible on model level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably can't because it depends of user interaction with your form: your server can't know in advance which element your user will select before sending the form to the browser. You could probably achieve this using ajax. I think a working process could be :

- Create a form with all the fields, and make `make` field [hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23463004/2844093)
- Create a view (I'll call it `AjaxMakeFieldView`) that will catch an ajax request taking a `vehicle_type` argument and return the HTML for `make field`, populated with relevant data. Add a URL in your URLConf for this view.
- In your template, add a Javascript binding : when user select a `vehicle_type`, the browser will send aan ajax request to `AjaxMakeFieldView` and replace hidden `make` field with returned HTML

If you don't want javascript, another way would be a two step form :

- A first form with a `vehicle_type` field
- Once the first form is submitted, your user get a second form with a `make` field, which initial data is populated depending of `vehicle_type` selected in the first form.

I've never done this, but [Django documentation on Form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) seems a good place to start.

Comment: JS solution is fine, but I would need some guide with it. What should I initialy render?

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry for not providing code sample, but I'm busy now. If you don't achieve what you want, just tell me, I'll try to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up having two model choice fields depending on each other, on one page. In the below, `field2` is depending on `field1`:

**Javascript portion**

Note that in `$.each()`, `$.parseJSON(resp)` should NOT be used (instead of just `json`) as we're already have it parsed by jQuery (due to the content_type='application/json' response) - see [I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#id_field2").empty();

    $("#id_field1").change(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'ajax_get_field_2' %}",
            type: 'GET',
            data:  {field1_id: $("#id_field1").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(resp){
                $("#id_field2").empty();
                $.each(resp, function(idx, obj) {
                    $('#id_field2').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', obj.pk).text(obj.fields.code + ' (' + obj.fields.affection + ')'));
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**Django views.py portion**

Note that this can probably be done by django-rest-framework as well.
I'm obtaining `fields=('id', 'code', 'affection'))` from my `MyModel2` - these can then be reached in JQuery using `obj.fielsd.<myfieldname>`.

```
class AjaxField2View(generic.View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        field_1 = get_object_or_404(MyModel1, pk=request.GET.get('field1_id', ''))
        model2_results = MyModel2.objects.filter(k_value=field_1 .k_value)
        return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', model2_results, fields=('id', 'code', 'affection')), content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another smart method **query/free and no views needed**,

is to make html tags for options that related to **field A choice**.

For example, in field B options:

```
<option example_tag="example_value" value="5"></option>
```

This tag should be related to either field A value or text.

Using JS to display block/none using this option tag accordingly.

And don't forget to reset value for every time user changes field A.