# Django forms - Dynamically update ModelChoiceField Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to update a form based on user selection of one field.
Here is my models.py

models.py

```
class A(Model):
    text = CharField()

class B(Model):
    a = ForeignKeyField(A)

class C(Model):
    a = ForeignKeyField (A)
    b = ForeignKeyField(B)
```

Assuming we use ModelChoiceField in forms.py.
Now if a user is adding a `C` object, and he selects an `A` object, I want to populate B field with `queryset=a.b_set`. Is there any way to do this in django? Or if I have to use Javascript, is there a best practice as to how to integrate this with django?
Thanks

Comment: It was already desided https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431827/django-model-choice-field-depend-on-other-fields-choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/PragmaticMates/django-clever-selects .

this library uses ajax under the hood and allows to add chained select widgets easily. I even customized it to work with mdl.